# MediaControllerCompat & MediaSessionCompat Android X?

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-mediasession

My imports for MediaControllerCompat & MediaSessionCompat

```
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;

private MediaSessionCompat mMediaSessionCompat;
private MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls mTransportControls;
```

I recently migrated my project to Android X, but these imports didn't change when migrating and instead added this in my gradle's dependencies.

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Now i was wondering why they didn't change to Android X, i searched for the android x dependencies for **MediaControllerCompat and MediaSessionCompat**, but i can't find them.

Comment: please post your error log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is intentional behavior: classes that are passed between processes  (such as `MediaSessionCompat.Token` that extends `Parcelable` or `MediaControllerCompat.Callback` that implements `IBinder.DeathRecipient`) cannot be moved to a new package without breaking cross compatibility between non-AndroidX projects and AndroidX projects. Therefore these classes had to be left in the original package.

This can be confirmed by looking at the [Support Library class mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings), which indicates that these specific classes maintain their existing package structure.

Answer (score 3):

In your gradle.properties you can see android.enableJetifier=true which handle all the third party libraries when we migrate our project in androidx the one property will handle all the migration stuff.

Now regarding your question, I have use both this class when I was working on mp3 audio app but after migrating to Androidx it still didn't added any extra library like.

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

My class :

```
package com.broadcast.audioplayerkotlin

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat
import android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat

import android.widget.SeekBar

import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat

import android.util.Log


class MediaSeekBar : AppCompatSeekBar {
private val TAG = "MediaSeekBar"
private var mMediaController: MediaControllerCompat? = null
private var mControllerCallback: ControllerCallback? = null
private var mIsTracking = false
private val mOnSeekBarChangeListener = object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {}

    override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
        mIsTracking = true
    }

    override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
        mMediaController?.transportControls?.seekTo(progress.toLong())
        mIsTracking = false
    }
}

constructor(ctx: Context) : super(ctx)
constructor(code: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(code, attrs) {

    super.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mOnSeekBarChangeListener)
}

constructor(code: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(code, attrs) {
}

override fun setOnSeekBarChangeListener(l: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener) {
    // Prohibit adding seek listeners to this subclass.
    throw UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot add listeners to a MediaSeekBar")
}

fun setMediaController(mediaController: MediaControllerCompat?) {
    if (mediaController != null) {
        mControllerCallback = ControllerCallback()
        mediaController.registerCallback(mControllerCallback!!)
    } else if (mMediaController != null) {
        mMediaController!!.unregisterCallback(mControllerCallback!!)
        mControllerCallback = null
    }
    mMediaController = mediaController
}

fun disconnectController() {
    if (mMediaController != null) {
        mMediaController!!.unregisterCallback(mControllerCallback!!)
        mControllerCallback = null
        mMediaController = null
    }
}

private inner class ControllerCallback : MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {

    override fun onSessionDestroyed() {
        super.onSessionDestroyed()
    }


    override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: PlaybackStateCompat?) {
        super.onPlaybackStateChanged(state)
        Log.d(TAG, "onPlaybackStateChanged: CALLED: playback state: " + state!!)

        val progress = state?.position?.toInt() ?: 0
        setProgress(progress)

    }

    override fun onMetadataChanged(metadata: MediaMetadataCompat?) {
        super.onMetadataChanged(metadata)
    }

    }
}
```

Gradle dependencies :

```
 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//RecyclerView
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'


def glideVersion = "4.8.0"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion"

// ExoPlayer
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.4' // 2.9.0 has min sdk 26

// Firestore
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
}
```

Just curious why added extra library.

Comment: In your dependencies you're using the support library and Android X.       (implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0')